# Comprehension of a logical expression in a while statement

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I have code that reads numbers from keyboard and sums them and outputs the sum when the loop terminates. The loop terminates when the number inputed is negative and divisible by 2 or it is positive and divisible by 3. But it is not working correctly. Where is the problem in the while condition?

```
while(!(n<0 && n%2==0) || !(n>0 && n%3==0))
```

Comment: @Atsch. While the phrasing is poor, there is a clear and unambiguous question here.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the negating logical expressions. The most simple way is to write a positive expression and the negate it with `!`:

```
!((n<0 && n%2==0) || (n>0 && n%3==0))
```

After that you can open the parentheses using Boolean algebra rules: when you open a negation statement you add a negation before each component and replace *OR* with *AND* and vice versa:

```
!(n<0 && n%2==0) && !(n>0 && n%3==0)
```

Using this rule you can continue opening the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

```
!(n<0 && n%2==0) || !(n>0 && n%3==0)
```

NOT (n is negative AND n is divisible by 2) OR NOT (n is positive AND n is divisible by 3).

This is a logical error NOT (A OR B) is not the same as (NOT A or NOT B), it is equal to NOT A and NOT B.

Check out:
http://integral-table.com/downloads/logic.pdf

Comment: de'morgan to the win :) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Thanks for your answers but this informations are not in the books of c++